# How to index SQLite tables?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite Database that making with DB Browser. This database is for a dictionary program And it contains a lot of columns. I added this database into the Android studio and read it with the Database Helper class. Loading these columns takes too much time. Isn't there any trick to reduce the loading time? one person told me to use the "sqlite indexing". How I can use this?

DataBaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_NAME = "database.sqlite";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private SQLiteDatabase mydatabase;
private Context context;
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
public void checkAndCopyDatabase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabases();
    if (dbExist) {
        Log.d("TAG", "already exist");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    try {
        copyDatabases();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", "Error copy DataBase");
    }
}
public boolean checkDatabases() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
    if (checkdb != null) {
        checkdb.close();
    }
    return checkdb != null ? true : false;
}
public void copyDatabases() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int lenght;
    while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
    }
}
public void openDatabase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mydatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mydatabase != null) {
        mydatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
public Cursor QueryData(String query) {
    return mydatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
}}
```

Load DataBase:

```
private void loadDatabase() {
    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getContext());
    try {
        dataBaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
        dataBaseHelper.openDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cursor = dataBaseHelper.QueryData(" SELECT name FROM dictionary ");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    item = new Info_Name_Main();
                    item.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                    arrayList.add(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    adapterMain = new Adapter_Name_Main(getActivity(), arrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMain);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you google "sqlite index". There are many tutorials and even official SQLite documentation that explains this concept.

Answer (score 0):

From the code shown, I don't believe that adding an index would help. That is the only access to the database is via `SELECT name FROM dictionary` so in the absence of any indexes (implicitly or explicitly defined) the index based upon the rowid will be used to scan the table, which should be the most efficient way; as per

> Access to records via rowid is highly optimized and very fast.[Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)

The above does assumes that dictionary isn't a view.

If it's taking too much time. You should investigate what the **it** is. Is it really the generation of the arrayList? Is it perhaps the copying of the data combined with the opening of the database? I'd start with adding some logging at pertinent points to try to ascertain where the bottlenecks are based upon the times.

**To answer the actual question you use the CREATE INDEX SQL as per :-**

[image]

[SQL As Understood By SQLite- CREATE INDEX](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

DB Browser, like any reasonable SQlite Manager will allow you to create them in a way similar to creating tables.